# Is it possible to add functionality to the middle of an extended method

Tags: python

Is it possible to modify/extend an inherited method from the middle. I realize I can call `super` and get the original method, then either put code before or after that call which will extend the original. Is there a technique of doing something similar but from the middle of a method?

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 4

    def get_data(self):
        data = []
        for num in range(self.size):
            data.append("doing stuff")
            data.append("doing stuff")
            ### add here from child##
            data.append("doing stuff")
            data.append("doing stuff")
        return data

class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get_data(self):
        # inherited parent code
        # Do something else here
        # inherited parent code
```

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot. You might as well just do a `ctrl-c-v` from the super class and modify the method in the child class.

Comment: By the way: this can be done with Beta-style prefixing. In Beta, you don't call the superclass method from the subclass method. Instead, superclass methods explicitly define their extension points, and call the subclass method. It's a quite interesting take on inheritance.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Cool I will look into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite Python's powerful introspection and code-modifying capabilities, there is no "clean" way of doing this. It could be done only by directly modifying the bytecode in the original function and shoehorsing a new method call in there - which would also implying in creating a new code and function objects - definitely not something to do in production code - even because bytecode is not guaranteed to be unchanged across Python versions or Python implementations.

## Refactoring the original method:

But it can be done if the original method is coded in a way it is "aware" of points were subclasses might want to run additional code (maybe even being split up in several methods):

For your example, you'd have something like:

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 4

    def get_data(self):
        self.data = data = []
        for num in range(self.size):
            data.append("doing stuff")
            data.append("doing stuff")
            self.do_extra_things_with_data()
            data.append("doing stuff")
            data.append("doing stuff")
        return data

    def do_extra_things_with_data():
        """Override this on subclasses"""

class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def do_extra_things_with_data():
        print(len(self.data), "objects defined so far")
```

One technical name for this is "slot". (It is used for templating in certain web frameworks - the derived page uses the parent template for columns and general layout, and defines "slots" for the content areas)
One other thing to watch are descriptors such as "properties": you can't change the superclass'method code - but if the code retrieves instance attributes for its computations, you can define these attributes as properties on the subclasses to run custom code.

## Using descriptors:

One other way of doing that is to use descriptors such as "properties": you can't change the superclass'method code - but if the code retrieves instance attributes for its computations, you can define these attributes as properties on the subclasses to run custom code.

Let's suppose your method makes use of the `self.size` attribute, but it is exactly for calculating it that you might want to run more code - keeping exactly the same Base class you can do:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    @property
    def size(self):
         # put extr calculation to retrieve the dynamc value
         of self.size here
         return value
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a technique of doing something similar but from the middle of
>   a method?

Not really.  The `def` compiles into a function object that has a self-contained code object that is usually treated as being opaque.

When a need like this arises, it is usually an indication that the parent method needs to be split into reusable components that can be called separately.

If you can't refactor the parent method, then the unfortunate alternative is that the subclass will have to override the method and duplicate some of the code from the parent.

In short, Pythonic object oriented design is treats methods and attributes as the atomic units of composability.

Comment: Thank you Raymond! I was messing around with decorators and thought something like this could be done but I'm still learning so I guess I will trust the master!